# Allow tables in content with CK-Editor

Tags: 7, nodes, wysiwyg

I have problems to configure my dupal 7 installation to allow entering tables.

*I will add the link to the page I mean because not everytime sure that I use the right words.*

I have created a type (admin/structure/types) which has four fields (admin/structure/types/manage/my-type-name/fields). The field body (admin/structure/types/manage/my-type-name/fields/body) has set filtered text as text processing. The selectbox under the CK-Editor has the value Filtered HTML. I tried to set its value to a custom clone of Filtered HTML which allows the attentional tags table, td, th and thead.

How can I allow tables for a special kind of type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Full Html to allow tr th and table but If you need to use Filtered HTMl for security reason you can use wysiwyg_filter Module that allow you to add some html tags to filtered html
about select box under ck-editor it's a permission problem that only filtered html appear

Answer (score 0):

Related issue at [CKEditor table td style not showing in frontend](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/217925/ckeditor-table-td-style-not-showing-in-frontend).

Check your ckeditor settings at /admin/config/content/ckeditor, had to disable "advanced content filter" (or well, reconfigure the editor), which was strapping all html tags not present in the editor features.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but after now more then 6 years this has no relevance for me. I even forgot that I have an account on this site ;-)